# REST request from one docker container to another fails

Tags: rest, docker, docker-machine

I have two applications, one of which has a RESTful interface that is used by the other. Both are running on the same machine.

Application A runs in a docker container. I am running it using the command line:

```
docker run -p 40000:8080 --name AppA image1
```

When I test Application B outside a docker container (in other words, before it is dockerized) Application B successfully executes all RESTful requests and receives responses without problems.

Unfortunately, when I dockerize and run Application B within a container:

```
docker run -p 8081:8081 --name AppB image2
```

whenever I attempt to send a RESTful request to Application A, I get the following:

```
Connect to localhost:40000 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused
```

Of course, I also tried making Application B connect using my machine's IP address. When I do that, I get the following failure:

```
Connect to 192.168.1.101:40000 failed: No route to Host
```

Has anyone seen this kind of behavior before? What causes an application that communicates perfectly well with another dockerized application outside a docker container to fail to communicate with that same dockerized application once it is itself dockerized???

Someone please advise...

Comment: Simply linking B to A `docker run -p 8081:8081 --link AppA --name AppB image2`, then you can access the REST service using `AppA:8080`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply linking B to A `docker run -p 8081:8081 --link AppA --name AppB image2`, then you can access the REST service using `AppA:8080`.

The reason is that Docker containers run on its own subnet (normally 172.17.0.0-255) and they cannot access the network that your host is on. Also `localhost` would be the container itself, not the host.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have another scenario: suppose AppB uses the Remote API to start up instances of AppA and then uses some RESTful command to set up those instances. I need to be able to run multiple instances of AppB at the same time and communicate with each instance using AppA after it has run them. Is there any way to distinguish between the different instances (they would all be using Port 8080!)?

Comment: I don't fully understand, but as long as each instance has a unique name then it's fine

Comment: I suspect that this is a completely different issue requiring a separate question. I will formulate a new question and ask it when I get the chance...

Comment: using --link is discouraged, see here: https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/#set-the-environment-variables-manually. "Where possible, you should avoid using the legacy --link flag"